# Beginner - Simple AJAX Web Servie call using Android SDK eclipe

Tags: android, ajax, eclipse, web-services

I am a beginner in learning Android app development. Here is my issue

I am using the eclipse given along with Android SDK to develop the Apps. To web enable the Apps i have used phonegap build tutorial to add cordova API. Now i am able to see the html file if i just use a normal HTML controls or text. But i have a code which calls a webservice from another WebSphere server and displays the data. When i run the code in IIS server (using DreanWeaver IDE) it works perfectly. But when i try to run this as an app in the emulator (From Android SDK) i dont see any output from the webservice. I can't even see a call from the android app to my webspehere server (which i can see when i run this code as a web page in Dreamweaver). Here is my index.html code. I have included the ws.js and prototype.js inside assets/www/scripts/ if anyone is wondering about that. Can somebody help me to resolve this issue.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ws.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function onBodyLoad(name, container)
    {
        console.log("Here1"); 
        var call = new WS.Call('http://localhost:9080/ILM/services/ILMReports'); 
        var nsuri = '';
        var qn_op = new WS.QName('getInboundSearchByItemReport',nsuri);
        var qn_op_resp = new WS.QName('getInboundSearchByItemReportResponse',nsuri);  

        call.invoke_rpc(
        qn_op,
        new Array(
        {name:'name',value:name}
        ),null,
        function(call,envelope) {
            var ret = 
            envelope.get_body().get_all_children()[0].
              get_all_children()[0].get_value();
            container.innerHTML = ret;
            }
        );

        /*window.location = "TestingAJAXWS.html";*/
    }

    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        // do your thing!
        navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working")
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad('aaa',$('result'))">
<h1>Hey, it's PhoneGap!</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem i can see is the localhost address you are using to access the web service.

Somehow android emulator don't allow to the localhost address as it is unknown to the emulator. (if you know the reason please write)

This is an old thread. But i hope it'l help somebody else.
/T